# Unable to set time zone in as.POSIXct function

Tags: r, timezone

```
Sys.timezone()
```

[1] "CST"

```
as.POSIXct("2012-12-12",tz="CST")
```

[1] "2012-12-12 GMT"

There were 13 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

I've set tz to CST, but the output is GMT, with warning messages, what went wrong?

Edit:

My OS is windows 7

warnings are:

```
Warning messages:
1: In strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) : unknown timezone 'CST'
2: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(x) : unknown timezone 'CST'
3: In strptime(xx, f <- "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) : unknown timezone 'CST'
4: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(x) : unknown timezone 'CST'
5: In strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = tz) : unknown timezone 'CST'
6: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(x) : unknown timezone 'CST'
7: In strptime(xx, f <- "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M", tz = tz) : unknown timezone 'CST'
8: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(x) : unknown timezone 'CST'
9: In strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d", tz = tz) : unknown timezone 'CST'
10: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(x) : unknown timezone 'CST'
11: In strptime(x, f, tz = tz) : unknown timezone 'CST'
12: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x, tz, ...), tz, ...) :
  unknown timezone 'CST'
13: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'CST'
```

Comment: Also, the time zones are system dependent so we need your OS.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName I've edit the post, add warnings and OS information.

Comment: Please read [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), the sections on the IANA time zone database and on POSIX time zones in particular.  I don't know enough about R to answer, but I know you should avoid posix time zones.  Also, there are at least [5 different meanings of "CST"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).  If R supports it, you should use IANA time zone identifiers, like `America/Chicago`.

Comment: The _See Also_ section of `?as.POSIXct` tells you to read `?Sys.timezone` to learn about the system-specific details of timezone implementations and how to specify valid strings.

Comment: Hi, I am OP, the problem is solved, I have added my solution below, sorry didn't tell you about that.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
as.POSIXct("2012-12-12",tz="CST6CDT")
```

Answer came from:
[unknown timezone name in R strptime/as.POSIXct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047188/unknown-timezone-name-in-r-strptime-as-posixct)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the list of valid names for tz parameter, they are all in the table in this web 
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
in the column of the name "TZ".

Comment: Those aren't necessarily valid names. As it says in the _See Also_ sections of `?as.POSIXct`, `?Sys.timezone` tells you how to determine the valid names on your specific system.