# how to extract timezone into column with POSIXct dates

Tags: r

I have these to dates in a dataframe and I would like to add a column that is the timezone

```
d = data.frame( dates =  c(as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 PDT"), as.POSIXct("2017-04-02 PST") ) )
d$TZ = attr(as.POSIXlt(d$dates), "tzone")  ### this doesn't do anything
d
```

when I try to add the timezone with :  `d$TZ = attr(as.POSIXlt(d$dates), "tzone")`  I get this error:

```
> d$TZ = attr(as.POSIXlt(d$dates), "tzone")
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "TZ", value = c("", "PST", "PDT")) : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 2
```

I'd like the output to be:

```
       dates    TZ
1 2017-01-01    PDT
2 2017-04-02     PST
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2017-01-01` shouldn't be `PDT`, the daylight-savings is wrong. This is why if you look at `d$dates` you'll see your time zones apparently reversed: R is "fixing the problem" (even if you didn't want it to). One might try using the `format=...` argument to `as.POSIXct`, but there is not `%`-code for time zone on the input, so that doesn't help.

Furthermore, the fact that `d$dates` shows time zones is because R thoughtfully (/carelessly?) assumed your local time zone when parsing the times. This can be shown by changing one of your dates to UTC:

```
d = data.frame( dates =  c(as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 PDT"), as.POSIXct("2017-04-02 UTC") ) )
d$dates
# [1] "2017-01-01 PST" "2017-04-02 PDT"
#                                  ^^^ is not UTC
```

Furthermore, R does not seem to understand `"PDT"` as a timezone:

```
as.POSIXct("2017-01-01", tz = "PDT")
# ... lots of warnings ...
# [1] "2017-01-01 GMT"
```

But it *does* accept something similar:

```
as.POSIXct("2017-01-01", tz = "PST8PDT")
# [1] "2017-01-01 PST"
```

If all you really want is the literal portion from the original string, then simply `d$TZ <- gsub(".* ", "", d$dates)` will give it to you, but if your intention is anything other than cosmetic/printing, these may not all be recognized by R. You may need to translate to something "known".

One way to go is to change the source to use hours-offset instead of timezone (e.g., `-0800` instead of `PDT`). Doing this, you can parse it with:

```
as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 -0500", format = "%Y-%m-%d %z")
# [1] "2016-12-31 21:00:00 PST"
as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 -0500", format = "%Y-%m-%d %z", tz = "UTC")
# [1] "2017-01-01 05:00:00 UTC"
```

(I'm assuming since you are using `as.POSIXct` vice `as.Date` that you want a date/time stamp, not just a date.)

Another method is to translate the suggested timezone among the list of known timezones. You can find the known timezones through [`?timezones`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/timezones.html) (another related Q/A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047188/unknown-timezone-name-in-r-strptime-as-posixct)).

After a little testing (please, test this further), I came up with this:

```
converttz <- function(x) {
  on <- OlsonNames()
  ind <- sapply(gsub(".* ", "", x), function(z) head(grep(z, on), n = 1))
  ret <- character(length(x))
  ret[lengths(ind) == 0] <- NA
  ret[lengths(ind) > 0] <- on[unlist(ind[lengths(ind) > 0])]
  ret
}
```

This works as long as case is correct; that is, `"est"` may just as easily match `"America/Creston"`, and even if you search only at the beginning or end of the strings, it could still match `"Europe/Budapest"`.

From here, something like this works:

```
dts <- c("2017-01-01 PDT", "2017-04-02 UTC")
d <- data.frame(dates = as.POSIXct(dts), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d$TZ <- converttz(dts)
str(d)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ dates: POSIXct, format: "2017-01-01" "2017-04-02"
#  $ TZ   : chr  "PST8PDT" "Etc/UTC"
```

Okay, so `"Etc/UTC"` isn't very sightly. `"UTC"` does exist in there, but it is the second one matched so is filtered out with `head`. You can try alternative methods for finding a closer match (perhaps looking for exact matches first, then beginning/end).