# Unused argument in Google Trends funcion (R)

Tags: r, google-trends

I am trying to retrieve a Google Trends query and I get the following error:

```
Error in gtrends(keyword = "hotel zypern", geo = "DE", time = "2004-01-01 2016-04-30",  : 
  unused argument (alist())
```

The code I  have written in R:

```
ger1<-gtrends(
  keyword = "hotel zypern",
  geo = "DE",
  time ="2004-01-01 2016-04-30",
  gprop = c("web", "news", "images", "froogle", "youtube"),
  category = "0",
  hl = "de",
  low_search_volume = FALSE,
  cookie_url = "http://trends.google.com/Cookies/NID",
  tz = "Europe/Berlin",
  onlyInterest = "FALSE",
)
```

I have tried including the "..." as other posts suggested, and revised the arguments of the function but I don't find anywhere that I should include such an argument.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

you had an extra comma in the end. Plus: it must be: `onlyInterest = FALSE` (without the semicolon, it's not a string, but boolean):

```
ger1<-gtrends(
    keyword = "hotel zypern",
    geo = "DE",
    time ="2004-01-01 2016-04-30",
    gprop = c("web", "news", "images", "froogle", "youtube"),
    category = "0",
    hl = "de",
    low_search_volume = FALSE,
    cookie_url = "http://trends.google.com/Cookies/NID",
    tz = "Europe/Berlin",
    onlyInterest = FALSE
)
```

I get a warning for this, but it works. If you want to avoid this, try setting your sys.setenv:

```
Sys.setenv(TZ="Europe/Berlin")
```

Like suggested here:
[unknown timezone name in R strptime/as.POSIXct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047188/unknown-timezone-name-in-r-strptime-as-posixct)

Answer (score 0):

You have a trailing comma at the end of the call, implying another argument. Remove that and you solve that error.

```
ger1<-gtrends(
  keyword = "hotel zypern",
  geo = "DE",
  time ="2004-01-01 2016-04-30",
  gprop = c("web", "news", "images", "froogle", "youtube"),
  category = "0",
  hl = "de",
  low_search_volume = FALSE,
  cookie_url = "http://trends.google.com/Cookies/NID",
  tz = "Europe/Berlin",
  onlyInterest = "FALSE"
)
```

You also need to watch out for the class of arguments you are passing to the function, for instance `onlyInterest` is looking for a boolean (FALSE), not a string ("FALSE").